# Numpy has no float attribute error when using Read_Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

When I try to read a xlsx file using pandas, I receive the error "numpy has no float attribute", but I'm not using numpy in my code, I get this error when using the code below

`info = pd.read_excel(path_info)`

The xlsx file I'm using has just some letters inside of it for test purpouses, there's no numbers or floats.

What I want to know is how can I solve that bug or error.

I tried to create different files, change my info type to specify a pd.dataframe too

Python Version 3.11
Pandas Version 1.5.3

Comment: Pandas wraps a lot of numpy. You need to give your versions of both and the traceback

Comment: Python Version 3.11
Pandas Version 1.5.3

Comment: As I said, you need to give the version of both, meaning pandas _and_ numpy, and also the traceback

Comment: What I think you're misunderstanding from my request is that pandas _cannot work without numpy_. So whether you interact with it directly or not, you _are_ using numpy. It gets installed by default when you install pandas

Comment: Sorry, numpy version is 1.24.0

Comment: Provide the traceback please.

Comment: numpy 1.24 dropped `np.float`, which has given rise to a lot of errors like this when used in older versions of other packages.  But pandas 1.5.3 should be new enough to not have this problem.  A full error traceback might help.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this issue by simply upgrading the openpyxl to latest version.
use the below mention snippet in your jupyter cell and execute.

```
!pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fixed it by updating openpyxl to latest version.